# Graphics card with better performance than AMD HD 7850

Tags: desktop, graphics-cards

### Introduction

I would like to purchase a graphics card (GPU) with a performance ~2x better than my current GPU, a Radeon HD 7850.

### Preferences

- Price < $120 (If it costs more and I can get it used for this price that's fine)
- Performance at least 2x better than the HD 7850
- Compatible with windows
- nVidia **preferable**, but anything more than a miniscule performance downgrade and I'll take AMD
- I can wait a few months if something is coming out
- I'd prefer not to do SLI/CrossFireX, but if the peformance benefit is substantial, I'll consider doing it with two cheap cards.
- TDP <= 300W

### Additional Information

- I play games such as Team Fortress 2, Trackmania 2, Trackmania United, Minecraft, SimCity 4, Hearthstone, Heroes of the Storm, and World of Warcraft.
- I also do Blender rendering, however this supports OpenCL and CUDA now so AMD is not a concern
- I have done my research and know about cards such as the GTX 960, GTX 770, R9 280X, R9 280, HD 7970, etc. I just want to know if there's something I've missed.

I would prefer if you provided benchmarks, links and maybe the occasional picture to back up your answer.

Comment: Given the games you play, I'm not sure your GPU is the part of your build that needs an upgrade, if you're looking for improved performance. That card should perform admirably (60+ fps) on all those titles as far as I know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing that meets both your price requirement and your performance requirement.

Price-wise, the traditional budget GPU is the 750 Ti at around $90-$100, but it's slightly *less* powerful than your current card; $120 gets you a factory-overclocked 750 Ti that just about matches your card for performance.

Performance-wise, three times your current performance is the GTX 980, at a price of around $400.

At twice your current performance, there's still nothing within your budget: the options are the GTX 970 (twice the specs) for $275, or the GTX 770 (twice the raw number-crunching ability, but only moderate gains in pixel-pushing) for $200.

The [Tom's Hardware GPU Hierarchy](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/gpu-hierarchy,4388.html) illustrates the problem you're running into: you're looking for something three to four tiers above your current card, and you're already near the top of the chart.

Comment: Oh dear - I meant ~2x, you can see the second time I put it in "Preferences". Sorry.

Comment: Still nothing in your price range.

Comment: that's unfortunate. I've been considering the RX 480 or GTX 960 as it goes down in price then (because of 1060 release). However, I have to say, the HD 7850 is nowhere near the top of the line - I would even go so far as to say it's mediocre :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have not upgraded:
I would recommend the [MSI GeForce GTX 1060 DirectX 12](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814137047&ignorebbr=1)

```
3GB 192-Bit GDDR5
Core Clock 1544 MHz
Boost Clock 1759 MHz
1 x DL-DVI-D 1 x HDMI 2.0 1 x DisplayPort 1.4
PCI Express 3.0 x16
```

Some Futuremark stats for both cards:

1. [HD 7850](http://www.futuremark.com/hardware/gpu/AMD+Radeon+HD+7850/review)
2. [GeForce GTX 1060-3GB](http://www.futuremark.com/hardware/gpu/NVIDIA+GeForce+GTX+1060-3GB/review)

[Anandtec review of the GTX 1060-3GB](http://www.anandtech.com/show/10580/nvidia-releases-geforce-gtx-1060-3gb)

Note, the anandtec review shows the EVGA card, but the MSI is the same chip.

Comment: The GTX 950 is overpriced, last-gen, and barely more powerful than my HD 7850. I have not upgraded though, so I am still open to suggestions.

Comment: Well, as in another post of yours, you may need to be flexible in your price area, as $120 will only get you so much.  Unless you are open to refurbished or used devices.

Comment: I admit, i speed read and miss things a bit, will look a bit further, after enduring the lecture I am sitting thru.

Comment: There changed to something closer to your proposed budget, and much better in performance and current gen.

Comment: Thank you -  I have been interested in this card in particular. Do you have any information regarding it's performance in relativity to my current graphics card? (HD 7850)

Comment: Edited answer to include benchmarks and an in depth review